# Does the use of place parameter in queries using the Facebook Graph API affect the results of post searches?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, rest

I 've been trying to test the place parameter when used for searching post using the Facebook Graph API. However it does not seem to affect results !!
For example:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=coffee&type=post&center=44,55&distance=1000

in the previous URL results do not change when I change the values of latitude and longitude (44,55) or the radius (1000)

Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the "distance" and "center" parameters only work when you use the parameter "type=place".

e.g. The two links below return demonstrate this.

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=coffee&type=place&center=44.270962,55.096039&distance=1000&access_token=[access_token]

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=coffee&type=place&center=53.270962,-6.096039&distance=1000&access_token=[access_token]

Once you have all the places returned, you could then do a further search on each place for their posts that contain coffee...